# How to make a GIF image keep moving while AJAX is in process?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add a very simple `loading GIF` in my AJAX. I use **[this](http://ajaxload.info/)** animated gif.But, the GIF only moves for 0,5-1s only. Then, 10 sec later the data form AJAX is displayed.

```
$('#btn_src').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some_function",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'some_var',
        success: function (data) {
            //some data from AJAX success call. 
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('.loading').hide();
            $('#myModal').modal('show'); //This is a modal to display the data from AJAX
        }
    });
});
```

The current AJAX have this behavior:

- Show GIF
- GIF stopped after moving for 0,1-1s
- 10s later the pop up is displayed. (So, before I see this pop up. There's a frozen gif in my screen).

What I expected is:

- Show GIF
- GIF keeps moving (As long as the seconds required for the data to be collected +1s )
- Hide GIF
- Show Pop Up

Comment: Your code is already running asynchronously, so what you want is what should be happening. How much data is being loaded? The only reason I can think of this happening is that the request retrieves a lot of data and that is taking some time to deserialise.

Comment: yes. there is a lot of data. That's why I need the loading keep spinning before all the data is collected

Comment: Can you provide the code for processing the data in the success function.

Comment: That's your issue then. I'd suggest getting much less data per request by using paging. You could combine that with some filtering logic too to further reduce the data being sent

Comment: Can I force the loading keep spinning? let's say for a 3-5s before frozen?

Comment: You could put the AJAX call in a `setTimeout()`, but I wouldn't really call that a workable solution. It just needlessly delays the user.

Comment: Which browser? Have you tried this in other browsers? Have you got something that we can check out?

Comment: I use most modern browser.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the browser cannot make the spinner spin while working on your data. First you will need to test with commenting out the whole content of `success`. If the spinner will not freeze then, that means that not the sheer size of data is the cause of this ui glitch, but the parsing. In this case you might want to modify your plan to divide the parsing job into chunks and call them bit by bit with little times between to allow the browser to handle the ui using `setInterval`, but don't forget to call `clearInterval` when the job is done. If the problem is with the sheer size of data, then you will either have to accept this behavior or to divide the responses into packets and send requests using `setInterval` until there are no more packets to receive.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
  $(document).ajaxStart(function () {            
        $('.loading').show()
    }).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, opts) {
        $('.loading').hide();
    }).ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, opts) {
        $('.loading').hide();
    }).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('.loading').hide();
    });
```

**or**

use **beforeSend** in ajax :

```
    $('#btn_src').on('click', function (e) {         
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "some_function",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: 'some_var',
            beforeSend: function (msg) {
              $('.loading').show();
            }
            success: function (data) {
                //some data from AJAX success call. 
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('.loading').hide();
                $('#myModal').modal('show'); //This is a modal to display the data from AJAX
            }
        });
    });
```